Finding help with psychological and emotional problems
I created this "question" as a resource that we can link to when self-help questions are posted. This is a work in progress. Feel free to edit this question (or its title) or provide an answer.
Do not discuss this question in comments or answers on this page. I want to keep this resource free of clutter. You can discuss this question here: Link list for self-help questions?
To do:

write a short introduction about the purpose of this resource
*write a general "tutorial" on how to go about finding help, if the country is not listed below

Finding Help
General online resources on finding psychological help
Resources by Country

Germany
United Kingdom
United States


Deutschland / Germany
Psychologische Beratung
Psychologische Beratung hilft bei der Bewältigung von Lebensproblemen psychisch gesunder Menschen.

TelefonSeelsorge
Die TelefonSeelsorge wird gemeinsam von der katholischen und evangelischen Kirche getragen. Die ausgebildeten ehrenamtlichen Mitarbeiter der TelefonSeelsorge hören Ihnen zu, wenn Sie Sorgen haben, sich einsam fühlen oder nicht mehr weiter wissen. Die Telefonseelsorge ist rund um die Uhr erreichbar.
http://www.telefonseelsorge.de
http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telefonseelsorge_Deutschland
pro familia
Beratung bei Fragen zu Sexualität, Schwangerschaft oder Partnerschaft sowie psychologische Beratung
http://www.profamilia.de
http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro_Familia_%28Deutschland%29
Caritas und Diakonie
Psychologische Beratung
http://www.caritas.de/hilfeundberatung/
http://www.diakonie.de/
Schulpsychologen
Beratung und Hilfe bei Schul- und Lernschwierigkeiten.
http://www.schulpsychologie.de/
http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schulpsychologe
Universitäten und Fachhochschulen
Alle staatlichen Hochschulen in Deutschland besitzen eine psychologische Beratungsstelle für Studierende und Mitarbeiter. 

Psychotherapie
Psychotherapie hilft bei psychischen Erkrankungen, psychischen Folgen körperlicher Erkrankungen und Problemen der Lebensführung.

Psychotherapie-Informations-Dienst
Telefonische Beratung des Berufsverbandes Deutscher Psychologinnen und Psychologen und Online-Suche nach Psychologischen Psychotherapeuten und Kinder- und Jugendlichenpsychotherapeuten
http://www.psychotherapiesuche.de
Bundespsychotherapeutenkammer
Online-Suche nach Psychologischen Psychotherapeuten und Kinder- und Jugendlichenpsychotherapeuten
http://www.bptk.de/service/therapeutensuche.html
Deutsche Psychotherapeutenvereinigung
Online-Suche nach Psychologischen Psychotherapeuten und Kinder- und Jugendlichenpsychotherapeuten
http://www.deutschepsychotherapeutenvereinigung.de/index.php?id=22
Kassenärtzliche Bundesvereinigung
Online-Suche nach Psychiatern und Psychologischen Psychotherapeuten
https://www.kbv.de/178.html


Just because it's for Germany doesn't mean it should be in German.

Just cuz cogsci.SE is in English doesn't mean the specifically German resources should be ;)

Translating what little text there is would lead to an ungainly mix of English text with German organizational names.

USA resources
(validity checked by @ChrisRogers Oct. 2021)
Information

How to Find an Anxiety Therapist
How to Find a Therapist
How to Find a Speech Therapist
Is Your Doctor Board Certified

US State Suicide HotlinesBefrienders Worldwide suicide prevention helplines
US National Toll-Free Self Help Telephone Numbers

I'm Alive
National Suicide Prevention Lifeline
RAINN (Rape, Abuse & Incest National Network)

Finding a therapist or doctor
The Psychologist Locator, a service of the American Psychological Association Practice Organization

The Psychologist Locator makes it easy for you to find practicing psychologists in your local area. Psychologists are trained to help people deal effectively with many of life's problems and can help improve physical and mental health for you and your family. The Psychologist Locator lets you consider many factors in searching for psychologists, including their areas of specialization, gender, insurance accepted, languages spoken and much more.

FindaPsychologist.org

An online resource featuring psychology-related content across a broad range of healthcare topics and a database of 10,500 licensed credentialed psychologists.


FindaPsychologist.org is a project of the National Register of Health Service Psychologists, a 501 (c)3 nonprofit dedicated to identifying qualified health service psychologists and providing healthcare consumers access to psychologists who meet credentialing quality standards.


Healthcare Topics & Issues
Self-Help Resources

TherapistLocator.net

Over 15,000 marriage and family therapists are listed in TherapistLocator.net. The therapists are Members of the AAMFT, and as such must meet stringent training and education requirements established by the AAMFT. All AAMFT Members have agreed to abide by the AAMFT Code of Ethics...Therapist Locator will provide you with information about a range of problems facing today's families, and help you search for a qualified family therapist in your area.

WebMD Physician Directory
Top Specialties [include the following relevant specialities

Emergency Medicine
Endocrinologist
Family Physician
General Practitioner
Neurologist
Ophthalmologist
Pain Management Doctor
Pediatrician
Psychiatrist
Psychologist
Sleep Specialist

healthfinder
Anxiety and Depression Association of America

General online resources
(validity checked by @ChrisRogers Oct. 2021)
Suicide Hotlines
International (Outside USA)
Befrienders Worldwide
Other Resources
MentalHelp.net
Hopeline's online chat support resources:

IMAlive


The first online network with 100% of its volunteers trained and certified in crisis intervention."


7 Cups of Tea


An on-demand emotional health and well-being service. Anyone who wants to talk about whatever is on their mind can quickly reach out to a trained, compassionate listener through this network."

Association for Behavioral and Cognitive Therapies Advanced Search page

Find an Acceptance and Commitment Therapist page

International Society for the Study of Trauma and Dissociation's Find a Therapist page
Information

Questions to Ask a Therapist During the First Session
How to Talk to a Therapist Geared toward Social Anxiety
Is Your Doctor Board Certified
What Is Informed Consent?
What Is Duty to Warn?
What Is a Psychological Disorder?

Kendra Cherry's articles on online therapy:

Online Therapy
Confidentiality in Online Therapy
Is Online Therapy Right For You?
Advantages and Disadvantages of Online Therapy

Journal Papers on Online Therapy

Drude, K., & Lichstein, M. (2005). Psychologists’ use of e-mail with clients: Some ethical considerations. Ohio Psychologist, 13-17. https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Kenneth-Drude-2/publication/242768600_Psychologists%27_Use_of_E-mail_with_Clients_Some_Ethical_Considerations/links/53e76c7b0cf25d674ea59d46/Psychologists-Use-of-E-mail-with-Clients-Some-Ethical-Considerations.pdf
Mulhauser, G. R. (2005). 9 Observations About the Practice and Process of Online Therapy. https://counsellingresource.com/lib/wp-content/managed-media/online-practice.pdf

International Society for Mental Health Online

Suggested Principles for the Online Provision of Mental Health Services

PsychCentral
Metanoia

**Talk to a Therapist Online**
"This is the only independent consumer guide to therapists and counselors who provide help over the Internet - compiled by consumers, for consumers."
How to Choose a Competent Counselor
If you are suicidal, read this first
Directory of Internet Psychotherapists


This is a comprehensive, independent consumer guide to the psychotherapists and counselors who provide services over the Internet. This guide is compiled by consumers, for consumers.


This directory gives you data about each therapists credentials, fees, payment options, services offered, and other relevant facts. But you must actually visit the therapists site for complete information about their services.


UK resources
Information
How to find a therapist
Psychotherapy is not regulated in the same manner as the US, however steps have been made to do the same.
If you wish to find a reputable therapist, make sure you search for one who is registered on any one of the accredited registers with the Professional Standards Authority such as:

National Counselling Society (NCS)
Play Therapy UK (PTUK)
UK Council for Psychotherapy (UKCP) or
British Association for Counselling and Psychotherapy (BACP)

Is Your Doctor Registered?
UK National Freephone Suicide Helpline

Samaritans

UK National Freephone Helplines

Stonewall (LGBTQIA+ Support)
Rape Crisis England and Wales For Women Only
Survivors UK (Male Rape ad Sexual Assault) For men and those supporting male survivors only
The Survivor's Trust (Rape, Sexual Abuse and Incest) For men and women, as well as their families
The National Association for People Abused in Childhood (NAPAC)

